# How can I log in to mysql without typing the root password?

Tags: mysql

For the last few years I logged in to my local mysql database by simply typing `mysql` on Terminal. But now, for some reasons I found that this doesn't work right now, with the access denied error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Now I must log in to type the following:

```
mysql -uroot -proot
```

This is quite painstaking, so I rather want to swich back to when I just type in `mysql` to log in to the database.

I don't set it as an alias in my zsh shell, but I cannot remember how I set it way before, such that I don't need to type in my user and password.

So how can I set it such that I log in with `mysql` command only? I use Mojave beta.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvotes? If it is the security concern, I'm fine with it, as I only use it on local environments, with no important database.

Answer (score -1):

I think your current connection has set up with a password try to create new connection with null  or leave it blank when asking a password  :)